# WSUS update directory is gone. Can I just create a new directory?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

I had my WSUS updates folder on my D: which is now gone.  If I can't get it back can I just create a new directory and then just re download the updates?  I am using the default WID DB so I'm not sure if that would have any effect on setting up a new folder.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Refer to TechNet documentation here:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/configurationmgr/2016/10/18/recreating-the-susdb-and-wsus-content-folder-for-a-windows-server-2012-based-wsus-computer/

Comment: you can also uninstall and re install the role

Comment: At the cost of a reboot, yeah.

Comment: I'd say 2 (1 for removal and 1 for install)

Comment: Well even worse. I shed a single tear for your uptime.

Comment: Either way is not working :P so It should not matter :)

Comment: Well tell us what happens when you try and I'm sure there is a solution. Although, given you're not OP you should probably submit another question.